# how does `mysqldump` generate the sql statements needed to restore the database?

Tags: mysql

how does the `mysqldump` command dump the sql statements needed to restore the database?

I noticed restoring a specific database from a dump file took around 40 seconds but creating the dump file from the same database took only 1 second approximately.

does the server maintain a file with the needed statements to restore the database, and just provide it to the user when we execute mysqldump? Or does it generate the needed statements again and again for each time we execute the mysqldump command?

Comment: The difference in processing time exists because creating a dump file and executing all the commands in the dump file are two totally different things. When recreting a database from a dump file many many more writing operations to separate files have to be done, indexes have to be recalculated and written, and, and, and...

Comment: okay. so does it generate statements again and again or it maintains a registry?

Comment: Neither nor. When you call mysqldump it does basically three things: 1. read the table setup form your database and compose a command to create exactly such a table. That is possible by simple means of string operations. 2. it reads the definitions of all indexes and creates statements to recreate them and 3. it selects all the data and creates insert statements from that. No magic involved here, no history required. Just reading data and creating sql statements. String operations in the end.

Comment: You can take a look at the source code of the utility if you are interested. It is open source.